# Can a setTimeout function fire before code infront of it has executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically I am trying to format some phone numbers before I submit them to the server using the following code.  I am submitting a home phone and a work phone, both inputs with a class of phone.

Note: I use the setTimeout because I am showing an ajax loader to give the impression that work is being done.

```
submitHandler: function(form){
  //Fires if validator plugin finds no errors
  //Cleanup Phone Numbers - Should receive phone numbers like (xxx) xxx-xxxx
  $("input.phone").each(function(){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,"").replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
  });

  setTimeout(function(){
    form.submit();
  }, 2500);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxk3F/2330/)

Why is it that I am sometimes neither home phone and work phone are properly formatted, sometimes both are properly formatter, or only home phone is properly formatted?

In my two specific cases where this has failed, I have received the numbers in xxxxxxxxxx format, which leads me to believe the second replace doesn't always work or the form is submitting before the second replace can fire in some instances.

Comment: Your formatting code will always run before the `form.submit()`, could it be that the formatting fails?

Comment: "I use the setTimeout because I am showing an ajax loader to give the impression that work is being done." - Plus in a future release, you get to cut it to 1250ms and claim a 50% performance improvement!

Comment: I think this is not a good practice. Call format function on submit and do submitting form from phone number format function after the format is complete

Comment: I guess you are having sync issues, I would use callbacks for chaining the functions.

Comment: Where is this code? on page load or on click?

Comment: @Dhunt this code is located in the submitHandler function of jQuery validate plugin which fires if everything IS VALID.

Comment: Are you sure the form isn't being submitted when you submit and then trying to be submitted again? You may need to preventDefault at the start of the handler. Although, then .submit() may just send you in a loop.

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: @ChristianJuth There really isn't much more code.

Comment: Is it possible that in the two cases where it has failed, the people submitting the numbers didn't have javascript enabled?  If you've designed your site to operate nicely, you'll support such users, but that would also stop both the validation and formatting code from running before the form is submitted.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I had considered that; however, this form cannot be submitted without javascript.

Comment: @JohnHargis Are you sure?  What does the `<form>` element look like?

Comment: @JamesThorpe The form element looks like a normal form element.  It is impossible to arrive at the submit button without it being shown with javascript or using developer tools to reveal the button along with the 5 sections of the form.  Trust me, someone would have to really go out of their way to submit it without JavaScript.

Comment: @JohnHargis Ok.  One last question though - is it also hidden with javascript?  Just want to completely rule it out - the javascript above itself looks fine.  Did the two you get submitted with the format not applied definitely have 10 digits (ie they matched the regex)?

Comment: @JamesThorpe  The submit button starts off hidden with css and is revealed with JavaScript.  As for the two that didn't work, both had ten digits.  On one of them, the home phone formatted properly(xxx-xxx-xxxx) and the work phone came through as xxxxxxxxxx.  Both home phone and work phone have the input class.  I will attach a link to the fiddle I am using to test.

Answer (score -1):

you may use focusOut/ focusIn such as

```
$("input.phone").focusOut(function(){
    alert('using ALERT Just for checking flow');
});
```